# PHP: .htaccess rewrite module

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page

```
http://www.mydomain.com/test.php?A=a/b/c.png
```

and on .htacess i have a code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^A/([^/]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L]
```

if I access

```
http://www.mydomail.com/A/a/b/c.png
```

it won't let me view the file but this rewrite rule is working with a delimiter "-"

```
RewriteRule ^A-([^-]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L]
```

access to url

```
http://www.mydomain.com/A-a/b/c.png
```

it works but I don't want to use delimiter "-" i want to use a delimiter "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your regex is wrong. Your URI has / in it and `[^/]` matches Everything but a slash.

Change your rule to this.

```
 RewriteRule ^A/([^.]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or this:

```
 RewriteRule ^A/(.+?)/?$ /test.php?A=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

***it's simple***

**The original URL:**

http://www.mydomain.com/test.php?A=a/b/c.png

**The rewritten URL:**

http://www.mydomain.com/A/a/b/c.png

**Use bellow htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^A/([^/]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L]
```

**If you want to use any prefix just use bellow code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /test.php?A=$1 [L]
```

-------------------------------------^ **use whatever with your needs**

If you want to be it like '`mydomain.com/images/a/b/c.png'`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L]
```

---------------------^ // removed A/ from here

Comment: how to put some prefixes before the it like I want the url to be 'http://www.mydomain.com/images/a/b/c.png'

Comment: i'm confused about your codes >.< RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L] it won't let me used mydomain.com/images/a/b/c.png

Comment: See last lines.mydomain.com/images/a/b/c.png'

Comment: I mean how to change "A/" to anything i want like i want to replace A to images so i can access it to http://www.mydomain.com/image/a/b/c.png the code won't work

Comment: RewriteRule ^A/([^/]*)$ /test.php?A=$1 [L] won't work it gives me 404 error